# Edit .GPX file to manually add laps?

Tags: gpx, strava

Here is my problem: I recently participated in a track race and recorded my activity with my GPS meter without taking the time to mark each lap. I would have liked to mark each lap after the recording but it seems that no tool exists for that.

I think that it is surely possible to do this by directly modifying the .gpx file of my activity with Notepad++ for example. However I can't find how to do it.

From what I understand .gpx files are structured as follows:

1. the first lines ( and <trk/name> or <trk/type>) contain general information about the activity (starting time and location, activity name...)
2. then comes the  section which contains the list of all recorded points with their associated data (cadence, power, heart rate in my case).

However, I don't see anywhere where the laps are marked.

Would you know how to do this?

Comment: The structure of a GPX file is governed by its schema ~ http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd  or see https://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/